# Angular *ngFor only showing 1 part of the data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I have some data that looks like this in the console:

Here is a screenshot of the console:

[image]

In app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let data of queryResult">
      {{data.City}}
</div>
```

This gives me 1 result when it should give my 615 (See the screenshot of a console.log on the data)

Here is the code in app.component.ts:

```
async testQuery() {
  const qry = 'SELECT * FROM myTable';
  await this.mysqlService.db.query(qry, (err , result) => {
    if ( err ) {
      console.log('err', err);
    } else {
      this.queryResult = [result];
      console.log(this.queryResult);

    }
  } );
}
```

How can I make it loop so it show's all of them instead of just 1?

Comment: Could you produce a minimal working example (eg. using Stackblitz)?

Comment: It seems to me that `queryResult` has a nested array that includes 615  elements. You're trying to iterate through an array with 1 element.

Comment: How do I do that? I've added the app.component.ts code to the question

Comment: is it supposed to be data.city? (lowercase)

Comment: No, it's data.City (uppercase C) ... It show's the result but only 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe try this:

```
<div *ngFor="let record of queryResult">
  <div *ngFor="let data of record">
    {{data.City}}
  </div>
</div>
```

or try this:

```
this.queryResult = result;
```

(no brackets)

Answer (score 1):

Use trackby. This solution helped me.

In app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let data of queryResult; trackBy:trackByEmpCode">
      {{data.City}}
</div>
```

In .ts:

```
trackByEmpCode(index: number, employee: any): string {
    return employee.City
}
```